# <noscript> tag merely prints enclosed HTML

Tags: javascript, html, http

```
<noscript><a style="text-decoration:none; border:0px;" href="http://server.website.com/ad?f&pid=2e9826de-a081-4f50-b771-9ae9145e123b&type=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test123.com&x=&y=" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://server.website.com/ad?f&pid=2e9826de-a081-4f50-b771-9ae9145e123b&type=1" width="300" height="250" /></a></noscript>
```

When this gets run on the first load with Javascript disabled it will just print to the screen without interpreting the HTML:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none; border:0px;" href="http://server.website.com/ad?f&pid=2e9826de-a081-4f50-b771-9ae9145e123b&type=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test123.com&x=&y=" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="http://server.website.com/ad?f&pid=2e9826de-a081-4f50-b771-9ae9145e123b&type=1" width="300" height="250" /></a>
```

Refreshing the page always displays it correctly.

Looking at the requests and responses nothing looks all that different from the ones that get served properly.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Seems like a bug in the browser to me. Which are you using?

Comment: Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m on Windows 7

Comment: And how are you disabling JavaScript?

Comment: chrome://settings/ > Advanced Settings > Content Settings > Do not allow any site to run Javascript

Comment: Hmm... Try it in another browser. If it works fine there, then it's a bug in Chrome and should be reported as such.

Comment: Seems to work fine on Firefox. I'll file a bug report when I have time.

Comment: Tested with the same Chrome version (Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m on Windows 7), with the same result. Just to make sure it’s not a problem in a particular installation. The innerHTML property of the noscript element has the content escaped so that e.g. “<” appears as “&lt;”, explaining the symptoms. So Chrome parses the content as plain text.

Comment: This only happens if the page is cached in the current session, you won't experience this problem via 1) w/ js enabled, open a new tab, load the page, notice the noscript doesn't show, 2) disable javascript, 3) close the tab, 4) open a new tab, load the page, notice the noscript shows and rendered HTML ; it is also worth noting that even the simplest of tags (e.g. `<p>hello</p>`) yields the same result, so it doesn't have to do w/ a) lack of a block element, b) malformed html (ampersand entities are missing in OPs `href`), c) image d) having `<script>` on the page makes no difference

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Wait, did you say "The innerHTML property of the noscript element"? But... that's a _contradictio in terminis_, isn't it?

Comment: By the way, this behaviour is also in Chromium 28, so it's been around for a while.

Comment: Zamnuts, that should be an answer -- it's excellent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested this on other major websites like Amazon, this is a bug in the browser. I filed a bug report and hope they will fix it. Not much else to do.